# Mapstruct: Mapping multiple source objects to subobjects

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

Given a set of four objects like:

```
A{String one, B b}

B{String two, String three}

C{String one, String two}

D{String three}
```

I wish to generate a mapping like:

```
A cAndDToA(C c , D d);
```

I cannot currently find a way to populate the B object inside of A with data from both C and D.

Does anyone know a solution to this issue, or have a better approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define a method for populating the `B` from `C` and `D`:

```
B cAndDToB(C c, D d);
```

And then invoke this manually via a [decorator](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.0/reference/html/index.html#customizing-mappers-using-decorators) on `cAndDToA`:

```
@Mapper(decoratedWith=MyMapperDecorator.class)
public interface MyMapper {
    A cAndDToA(C c, D d);
    B cAndDToB(C c, D d);
}

public abstract class MyMapperDecorator implements MyMapper {

    private final MyMapper delegate;

    public MyMapperDecorator(MyMapper delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public A cAndDToA(C c, D d) {
        A a = delegate.cAndDToA( c, d );
        a.setB( cAndDToB( c, d );

        return a;
    }
}
```

We will offer support for [nested mappings](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.0/reference/html/index.html#nested-mappings) on the target side, too. But we are not there yet :)

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for the suggestion. I am very impressed with this library so far, and look forward to the implementation of those nested mappings.